# CMake: undefined reference to boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I added boost via this:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

project(APP C CXX)
add_executable(APP src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(APP ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

And when I compiled source, I got:

```
demo.cpp:(.text+0x3d3): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

I checked spelling (Boost_LIBRARIES vs BOOST_LIBRARIES) but it's ok.

I installed boost in Fedora with the package boost-devel.

Comment: what is the content of `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`?

Comment: It should be path to static boost lib ( https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html )

Comment: there is no "one" static boost lib. And can you print it and not what it "should be"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1775), `Boost_LIBRARIES` is filled according to the component list passed to `find_package`. Try:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
```

You should also use imported targets:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

# the call to include_directories is now useless:
# the Boost::system imported target used below
# embeds the include directories

project(APP C CXX)
add_executable(APP src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(APP Boost::system)
```

Comment: cmake fail to locate boost_system ... I have installed boost-system but boost-system-dev doesn't exists

Comment: just for others: the link syntax `Boost::<component>` will automatically add the include directory to your target. That is why `include_directories` is "useless" here

Comment: @Seraph to use the library you need the "-dev" version while building

Comment: boost-system have no -dev version (or fedora doesn't have it ...)

Comment: After setting set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       OFF) instead of ON, it works, but it uses shared lib right? So boost is not embedded in app ?

Comment: @Hayt you're right, less ambiguous with the explanation. I edited my answer

Comment: @Seraph It seems that you need to install a package named [`boost-static`](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=7915998).